# Why my HashMap puts an element in position 6 instead of the next empty position?

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm running the following code in a method, but at the time of return the key and value <"dataInicio">,<"orange"> are at position six of the map instead of position one like it should've. What could be doing this?

I'm creating this map to sends as parameter to a Jasper report and it puts dataInicio in position six, then puts dataFim in position one and listaParametros in position three. It's crazy.

Here's the code:

```
 final Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        parameters.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", "apple");
        parameters.put("dataInicio", "orange");
        parameters.put("dataFim", "melon");
        parameters.put("listaParametros", "banana");
        return parameters;
```

And here's the eclipse print screen of the Expressions view:[image]

Comment: Because that's how the HashMap works - the keys are inserted into buckets according to their hash code, the order of insertion is not preserved. You might want to try a list of `String, Object` pairs.

Comment: Why should it be at position 1?

Comment: Other people told you about `HashMap`, but there are other `Map` implementations (e.g., `TreeMap` and `ConcurrentSkipListMap`) that keep the keys sorted according to their natural ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the whole point of `HashMap`.  It is, in fact, what it means by the word "hash."  Elements are supposed to be put in essentially random positions in the table -- the hash code mod the table size, in many cases.

This is part of why the documentation of `HashMap` states that "This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time."

Comment: If you use a `LinkedHashMap`, you can preserve insertion-order, but the backing-store is still a hash table, so your data will be re-arranged in this objectionable way. The good news is that you can get it back out in a predictable order.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I should define the report parameters in the same order they are arranged in the map, so if it has elements, empty buckets and then the element I need in position six I don't think it'll work.

Comment: No, LinkedHashMap should take care of that.  There's no way to observe the bucket ordering externally via the API, you can only see it via the debugger.  LHM will work.

Comment: @StudioWorks JasperReports doesn't care about the order of the parameters, since they are named within the `Map`. Don't worry about the order; JasperReports will do the right thing.

Comment: Saying "random position" is a weak way of describing the real goal which is that any given set of keys should be _uniformly distributed_ to the buckets.

Comment: This is true, but "random" reordering is the primary implication for *consumers* of the API, who mostly only care that the ordering is shuffled in a chaotic way.  Uniform distribution is primarily of interest to the implementer, not the consumer.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz Ok, knowing that changes things. I'm getting java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource and thought that was the problem.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I figured it out. I was sending a parameter of a different type to a subreport I had in my report, but I got distracted thinking the error was about the order of my parameters. Thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 2):

Hash map are not lists, the index is calculated with a hash function depending on the data you are storing in. In fact, sometimes different datas get the same index, when this happends, hash maps has a mechanism to assign a different index to one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Because that's how the `HashMap` works - the keys are inserted into buckets according to their hash code, the order of insertion is not preserved. You might want to try a list of `String, Object` pairs or a `LinkedHashMap` (which won't change anything regarding the internal storage, but at least is able to return the values in the order of inserting).

Comment: In my understanding I have to set the report parameters in the same order I declare them in the code. I used LinkedHashMap, but as you pointed out it doesn't change it's internal storage so I get the same error because the order of the elements in the Map is different to how it's declared in the report. Have any ideas?

Comment: @StudioWorks: What error do you get exactly? Or: How are you reading the values afterwards?

Comment: I figured it out. It's in my comments. Thanks for the help.